# OSError:16[one of the data] not found

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read my dataset and deal with it.
However, when I run my read-in test programme, something went wrong.
The terminal print:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\demo\code\aRIOU\RandLA-Net-pytorch-master\t.py", line 14, in <module>
    points.append(np.loadtxt(line, dtype=np.float32))
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch1.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 961, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch1.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 195, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch1.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 535, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: 16 not found.
```

the number "16" is the data in my dataset:"1.txt".

I have no idea, and I have searched a lot, but still cannot find a solution.
Here is part of my code.Thanks a lot for helping me.

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm


points = []
print(points)
p = (Path(__file__) / '..').resolve()

pc_path =  p / '1.txt'
print(pc_path)
with open(pc_path, 'r') as file :
    for line in tqdm(file):
        points.append(np.loadtxt(line, dtype=np.float32))
        print(points)
        points = np.array(points)
```

Comment: Your exception is happening on `points.append(np.loadtxt(...))` -- the stack trace is telling you exactly what the problem is. It can't open a file called `16`. From the numpy docs: `numpy.loadtxt(fname, ...)` --> `fname:` "File, filename, or generator to read". My best guess is your '1.txt' is not formatted properly. See [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: OK, I learned something cool today: `pathlib.Path`, letting you just type `pc_path = p / '1.txt'` to concatenate paths. Love it!

Comment: But, to your question, does `1.txt` contain a list of files to load with `np.loadtxt`? That's what your code appears to try to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I have found the solution. After reading the docs, I saw an example: `     >>> from io import StringIO   # StringIO behaves like a file object
    >>> c = StringIO("0 1\n2 3")
    >>> np.loadtxt(c)
    array([[0., 1.],
           [2., 3.]])`    I just use the function "StringIO()" to process my data---line, and it seems to be all right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I think I have found the solution. After reading the docs, I saw an example:

```
    >>> from io import StringIO   # StringIO behaves like a file object
    >>> c = StringIO("0 1\n2 3")
    >>> np.loadtxt(c)
    array([[0., 1.],
           [2., 3.]])
```

and it  Note that generators should return byte strings.
I just use the function "StringIO()" to process my data---"line", and it seems to be all right.